# What's the difference between "to stroll" and "to wander"?

Tags: difference, verbs, synonyms

I see a lot of people claiming that these two verbs really mean the same thing **always** or are used interchangeably, but I'm not sure about it because I think two words can share the same meaning for a certain context (i.e they can be synonyms)- but in some cases one communicates the idea better than the other. So, what's the difference between "to stroll" and "to wander"?

Comment: I agree with @Michael Harvey and would add that you can wander in a leisurely way, or not.

Answer (score 3):

To stroll is to walk in a leisurely way, and the focus is on the mode of travel. To wander is to walk or run, at any speed, without a fixed course or destination, and the focus is on that. You can stroll with a destination in mind, or not. If you stroll aimlessly you are wandering.

The verbs may be used together, and often can be interchanged, depending on the emphasis intended:

> I wandered around the park, strolling from tree to tree.
>
> I strolled around the park, wandering from tree to tree.

Answer (score 1):

"Stroll" is about speed. "Wander" is about direction.

To stroll is to walk slowly, or as a noun, a stroll is a gentle hike.

> We strolled from the town centre back to my home, chatting all the way.

If you wander, you don't walk straight.

> We wandered through the forest, sometimes following the stream, sometimes walking away from it.

Both imply that you are not walking urgently, and often you would wander at a strolling pace, or while you are on a stroll, you would tend to wander.